# in my new Django project my html file isn't rendering

Tags: python, html, django

When I have my index.html file inside the template folder alone, it renders fine. However, when I put my app name as a folder inside of the template folder, the page doesn't render. I am sure the file path is correct, and the html file is correct except for one line of h1.

urls.py (entire project level)

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('students.urls')),
]
```

urls.py (students app level)

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

views.py (students app level)

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'students/index.html')
```

Comment: Could you add the path for your index.html file and your template settings (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/templates/#configuration) if you have one?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the templates directory is included in your Django project's settings.py file,

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates") 
...
]
```